# Java Timer: local variable count defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final

Tags: java, timer

This is My code,

```
public void sendSMS() throws InterruptedException {
    int count=0;
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Sending Client SMS At: "+Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            System.out.println("Sending SMS");
            count++;
            if(count>=4) {
                System.out.println("Cancelling timer Thread");
                cancel();
            }
        }
    };
    
    Timer timer = new Timer("TimerThread");
    timer.schedule(task, 0, 2000l);
}
```

I want to stop the Timer when count=4. But the count variable is not accessible in the inner class. according to My requirement, stopping the Timer should have happened inside the newly started timer thread(inside the run method) since the outer thread cannot wait until the Timer thread is over. I want a method to access the count variable or stop the timer at some value of count.
Please Help Me.

Comment: Can you post a longer code? or this is all method? also, which Java version you use? I can't reproduce this on JDK11.

Comment: I changed the code several times for the betterment and Sorry for the inconvenience that happened. @Giorgi Tsiklauri yes I'm using JDK 11 and there is no other code.

Comment: Something is copied inaccurately. I compile this code fine and there is no problem. Using OpenJDK 11.

Comment: Ok, you've changed your code. Now I've changed my answer. See it, it should help you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a primitive, you should use a mutable wrapped integer class that is final or effectively final.

For instance you can use `AtomicInteger` class in the standard library, or just write your own simple `MutableInteger` class.

Direct translation of your code into using this idea:

```
public void foo() throws InterruptedException {
    AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            count.set(2); // I'm assuming this would be something else
            System.out.println(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            if(count.get()>=4) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                cancel();
            }
        }
    };

    Timer timer = new Timer("TimerThread");
    timer.schedule(task, 0, 2000l);

    Thread.sleep(7000l);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A work around for that, besides using `AtomicInteger` is to use an array

```
    public void sendSMS() throws InterruptedException {
        final int[] count = new int[] {0};
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Sending Client SMS At: " + Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                System.out.println("At Some Conditions Sending SMS and repeat");
                if (count[0] >= 4) {
                    count[0]++;
                    System.out.println("Cancelling timer Thread");
                    cancel();
                }
            }
        };
        Timer timer = new Timer("TimerThread");
        timer.schedule(task, 0, 2000l);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Sending Client SMS At: "+Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            System.out.println("Sending SMS");
            count++;
            if(count>=4) {
                System.out.println("Cancelling timer Thread");
                cancel();
            }
        }
```

Write this:

```
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Sending Client SMS At: "+Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            System.out.println("Sending SMS");
            int ctn=count; //declare a new local to anonymous class variable, and use it instead.
            ctn++;
            if(ctn>=4) {
                System.out.println("Cancelling timer Thread");
                cancel();
            }
        }
```

You need to redefine your out of scope variable's value inside an anonymous inner class. [This](https://www.javahabit.com/2016/06/16/understanding-java-8-lambda-final-finally-variable/) will help you understand more.